# To prove $2^{n(n+1)} >(n+1)^{(n+1)} \prod\limits_{j=1}^n \left(\dfrac {j}{n+1-j}\right)^j , \forall n\in \mathbb N $ \ { $1$ }

Tags: inequality

How do we prove that $2^{n(n+1)} >(n+1)^{(n+1)} \prod_{j=1}^n \Bigg(\dfrac {j}{n+1-j}\Bigg)^j  , \forall n\in \mathbb N$ \ {$1$}  ?

Comment: It is false for $n=1$. Either use $\ge$ in the inequality or $n>1$.

Comment: @gammatester:- just fixed it

Comment: 0 is not considered a natural number here

Comment: It can be written as $2^{n(n+1)}>\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}j^{2j-(n+1)}$.

Comment: @user2345215:- How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decrease $n$ by $1$ and simplify:
$$n^n\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac j{n-j}\right)^j=\frac{n^n\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}j^j}{\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)^j}=\frac{\prod_{j=1}^nj^j}{\prod_{j=1}^nj^{n-j}}=\prod_{j=1}^nj^{2j-n}$$
We want to prove $\prod_{j=1}^{n}j^{2j-n}<2^{n(n-1)}$. It's trivial to verify it for $n=3$, so suppose it holds for some $n$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}\prod_{j=1}^{n+1}j^{2j-(n+1)}&=(n+1)^{n+1}\prod_{j=1}^n\frac{j^{2j-n}}j=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!}\prod_{j=1}^nj^{2j-n}<\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!}2^{n(n-1)}\\&=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!\,2^{2n}}2^{n(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n!\,4^n}2^{(n+1)((n+1)-1)}\end{align}$$
So we are done if we prove $n!\,4^n\geq(n+1)^{n+1}$. It clearly holds for $n=1$. Suppose it holds for numbers less than $n$, then
$$n!\,4^n=4n\,(n-1)!\,4^{n-1}\geq4n\cdot n^n=4n^{n+1}$$
It suffices to show that $4\geq\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}}=\big(1+\frac1n\big)^{n+1}$. This is true, because it holds for $n=1$ and it's a well known decreasing sequence (see [planetmath](http://planetmath.org/11nnisanincreasingsequence#Thmthm2)).